# I failed to train CNN + LSTM model. How can I solve this problem? Is it have problem in dataset? or model? (Python 3.8x)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

## 0. I used:

- Python 3.8x
- JupyterLab >=3.0
- Tensorflow
- Keras
- VGG19 (pre-trained model)

## 1. My Problem

I tried to train CNN + LSTM Python model to video classification(Binary Classification).

**But... I failed to train my model.** My JupyterLab(>=3.0) only printed `Epoch 1/100` and almost stopped, or restarted kernel(I suggested that maybe memory is insufficient, but my desktop has 16GB RAM!).

Have I make wrong model? or Is it wrong with my datasets?

Also, sometimes I reduced the size of training data.(2000 -> 100) But the problem wasn't solved.

Here's my model and dataset's structure.

## 2. Input Data shape(My datasets)

### Data : data_training_ar

- type : numpy array
- shape : (2697, 30, 160, 160, 3)

It has 2697 video's 160*160 sized RGB ndarray. Each video has 30 frame.

- example : data_training_ar[10]

```
array([[[[0.03105 , 0.02397 , 0.02713 ],
         [0.08167 , 0.0738  , 0.0777  ],
         [0.1142  , 0.1064  , 0.1103  ],
         ...,
         [0.183   , 0.1752  , 0.1713  ],
         [0.12427 , 0.11646 , 0.1137  ],
         [0.01765 , 0.0098  , 0.00784 ]],

        [[0.1113  , 0.1051  , 0.1074  ],
         [0.5225  , 0.5146  , 0.5186  ],
         [0.3794  , 0.3713  , 0.3755  ],
         ...,
         [0.2229  , 0.2151  , 0.2112  ],
         [0.1255  , 0.1177  , 0.1137  ],
         [0.013725, 0.00816 , 0.005882]],

        [[0.124   , 0.11615 , 0.1201  ],
         [0.4556  , 0.4478  , 0.4517  ],
         [0.3982  , 0.3904  , 0.3943  ],
         ...,
         [0.1613  , 0.1534  , 0.1495  ],
         [0.1173  , 0.10956 , 0.1075  ],
         [0.0098  , 0.005882, 0.005882]],

        ...,

        [[0.08453 , 0.08246 , 0.08246 ],
         [0.4902  , 0.498   , 0.4863  ],
         [0.5337  , 0.5728  , 0.5337  ],
         ...,
         [0.9883  , 0.9883  , 0.9883  ],
         [0.9883  , 0.9883  , 0.9883  ],
         [0.9883  , 0.9883  , 0.9883  ]],

        [[0.08234 , 0.0807  , 0.08466 ],
         [0.482   , 0.4941  , 0.4883  ],
         [0.51    , 0.554   , 0.521   ],
         ...,
         [0.9766  , 0.9766  , 0.9766  ],
         [0.9663  , 0.9663  , 0.9663  ],
         [0.9683  , 0.9683  , 0.9683  ]],

        [[0.08234 , 0.0843  , 0.0863  ],
         [0.4824  , 0.496   , 0.4902  ],
         [0.51    , 0.551   , 0.5195  ],
         ...,
         [0.4133  , 0.4133  , 0.4133  ],
         [0.3955  , 0.3955  , 0.3955  ],
         [0.3523  , 0.3523  , 0.3523  ]]],


       [[[0.01689 , 0.01221 , 0.01296 ],
         [0.0955  , 0.08765 , 0.09155 ],
         [0.1139  , 0.1061  , 0.11    ],
         ...,
         [0.179   , 0.1711  , 0.1672  ],
         [0.12354 , 0.11566 , 0.11255 ],
         [0.01645 , 0.0098  , 0.0098  ]],

        [[0.11365 , 0.10583 , 0.10974 ],
         [0.5186  , 0.5107  , 0.5146  ],
         [0.3809  , 0.373   , 0.377   ],
         ...,
         [0.232   , 0.2242  , 0.2203  ],
         [0.1232  , 0.11566 , 0.11176 ],
         [0.013725, 0.0098  , 0.00784 ]],

        [[0.135   , 0.1274  , 0.1311  ],
         [0.4604  , 0.4526  , 0.4565  ],
         [0.3862  , 0.3784  , 0.3823  ],
         ...,
         [0.1727  , 0.1648  , 0.1609  ],
         [0.11115 , 0.10333 , 0.09937 ],
         [0.013725, 0.00784 , 0.005882]],

        ...,

        [[0.07855 , 0.0787  , 0.0745  ],
         [0.4788  , 0.4963  , 0.4785  ],
         [0.5337  , 0.563   , 0.5317  ],
         ...,
         [0.9883  , 0.9883  , 0.9883  ],
         [0.9883  , 0.9883  , 0.9883  ],
         [0.9883  , 0.9883  , 0.9883  ]],

        [[0.0745  , 0.0804  , 0.0784  ],
         [0.4727  , 0.496   , 0.4805  ],
         [0.5137  , 0.551   , 0.5254  ],
         ...,
         [0.9717  , 0.9717  , 0.9717  ],
         [0.974   , 0.974   , 0.974   ],
         [0.973   , 0.973   , 0.973   ]],

        [[0.0745  , 0.08234 , 0.0804  ],
         [0.4727  , 0.498   , 0.4844  ],
         [0.5137  , 0.551   , 0.5254  ],
         ...,
         [0.4067  , 0.4067  , 0.4067  ],
         [0.3923  , 0.3923  , 0.3923  ],
         [0.3586  , 0.3586  , 0.3586  ]]],


       [[[0.01689 , 0.01025 , 0.01296 ],
         [0.09265 , 0.07965 , 0.0836  ],
         [0.12445 , 0.1053  , 0.11    ],
         ...,
         [0.172   , 0.1674  , 0.1635  ],
         [0.111   , 0.1149  , 0.10706 ],
         [0.00784 , 0.008606, 0.00784 ]],

        [[0.1068  , 0.0996  , 0.1029  ],
         [0.522   , 0.5117  , 0.5156  ],
         [0.3933  , 0.3755  , 0.3813  ],
         ...,
         [0.2363  , 0.2305  , 0.2249  ],
         [0.1209  , 0.1213  , 0.1134  ],
         [0.00784 , 0.00948 , 0.00784 ]],

        [[0.1294  , 0.1239  , 0.1257  ],
         [0.4658  , 0.4563  , 0.46    ],
         [0.395   , 0.3796  , 0.3835  ],
         ...,
         [0.1705  , 0.1627  , 0.1588  ],
         [0.1207  , 0.11676 , 0.111   ],
         [0.00968 , 0.00968 , 0.005882]],

        ...,

        [[0.0726  , 0.0784  , 0.0727  ],
         [0.471   , 0.4963  , 0.4749  ],
         [0.528   , 0.565   , 0.5317  ],
         ...,
         [0.9883  , 0.9883  , 0.9883  ],
         [0.9883  , 0.9883  , 0.9883  ],
         [0.9883  , 0.9883  , 0.9883  ]],

        [[0.0745  , 0.0804  , 0.0784  ],
         [0.4727  , 0.496   , 0.4805  ],
         [0.517   , 0.5547  , 0.5293  ],
         ...,
         [0.977   , 0.977   , 0.977   ],
         [0.9707  , 0.9707  , 0.9707  ],
         [0.9766  , 0.9766  , 0.9766  ]],

        [[0.0745  , 0.08234 , 0.08234 ],
         [0.4746  , 0.498   , 0.4844  ],
         [0.5137  , 0.5527  , 0.5254  ],
         ...,
         [0.4087  , 0.4087  , 0.4087  ],
         [0.3977  , 0.3977  , 0.3977  ],
         [0.3484  , 0.3484  , 0.3484  ]]],


       ...,


       [[[0.01778 , 0.01778 , 0.01778 ],
         [0.08307 , 0.08307 , 0.08307 ],
         [0.1046  , 0.1046  , 0.1046  ],
         ...,
         [0.1659  , 0.1744  , 0.1631  ],
         [0.08594 , 0.0938  , 0.0899  ],
         [0.00784 , 0.011765, 0.011765]],

        [[0.0795  , 0.0795  , 0.0795  ],
         [0.4434  , 0.4434  , 0.4434  ],
         [0.3796  , 0.3796  , 0.3796  ],
         ...,
         [0.2612  , 0.2708  , 0.2573  ],
         [0.1079  , 0.1157  , 0.11017 ],
         [0.00784 , 0.011765, 0.011765]],

        [[0.0664  , 0.0664  , 0.0664  ],
         [0.3572  , 0.3572  , 0.3572  ],
         [0.388   , 0.388   , 0.388   ],
         ...,
         [0.1753  , 0.1792  , 0.1674  ],
         [0.1013  , 0.1054  , 0.10144 ],
         [0.00772 , 0.01164 , 0.01152 ]],

        ...,

        [[0.08234 , 0.0784  , 0.0844  ],
         [0.512   , 0.512   , 0.516   ],
         [0.563   , 0.563   , 0.557   ],
         ...,
         [0.9844  , 0.9844  , 0.9844  ],
         [0.9883  , 0.988   , 0.9883  ],
         [0.9883  , 0.988   , 0.9883  ]],

        [[0.0843  , 0.08264 , 0.0843  ],
         [0.506   , 0.506   , 0.506   ],
         [0.549   , 0.549   , 0.549   ],
         ...,
         [0.972   , 0.972   , 0.972   ],
         [0.9766  , 0.9766  , 0.9766  ],
         [0.9727  , 0.9727  , 0.9727  ]],

        [[0.0843  , 0.0843  , 0.0843  ],
         [0.506   , 0.506   , 0.506   ],
         [0.547   , 0.547   , 0.547   ],
         ...,
         [0.4138  , 0.4138  , 0.4138  ],
         [0.3975  , 0.3975  , 0.3975  ],
         [0.3496  , 0.3496  , 0.3496  ]]],


       [[[0.01581 , 0.01581 , 0.01581 ],
         [0.0835  , 0.0835  , 0.0835  ],
         [0.1042  , 0.1042  , 0.1042  ],
         ...,
         [0.1631  , 0.1725  , 0.1611  ],
         [0.08594 , 0.0938  , 0.0899  ],
         [0.00784 , 0.011765, 0.011765]],

        [[0.07623 , 0.07623 , 0.07623 ],
         [0.442   , 0.442   , 0.442   ],
         [0.3748  , 0.3748  , 0.3748  ],
         ...,
         [0.2605  , 0.269   , 0.257   ],
         [0.1082  , 0.116   , 0.1118  ],
         [0.00784 , 0.011765, 0.011765]],

        [[0.0646  , 0.0646  , 0.0646  ],
         [0.3538  , 0.3538  , 0.3538  ],
         [0.3918  , 0.3918  , 0.3918  ],
         ...,
         [0.1735  , 0.1792  , 0.1655  ],
         [0.1013  , 0.10724 , 0.10333 ],
         [0.00772 , 0.01164 , 0.01152 ]],

        ...,

        [[0.08234 , 0.0784  , 0.0844  ],
         [0.512   , 0.512   , 0.516   ],
         [0.563   , 0.563   , 0.557   ],
         ...,
         [0.9844  , 0.9844  , 0.9844  ],
         [0.9883  , 0.988   , 0.9883  ],
         [0.9883  , 0.988   , 0.9883  ]],

        [[0.0843  , 0.08264 , 0.0843  ],
         [0.506   , 0.506   , 0.506   ],
         [0.549   , 0.549   , 0.549   ],
         ...,
         [0.972   , 0.972   , 0.972   ],
         [0.9766  , 0.9766  , 0.9766  ],
         [0.9727  , 0.9727  , 0.9727  ]],

        [[0.0843  , 0.0843  , 0.0843  ],
         [0.506   , 0.506   , 0.506   ],
         [0.547   , 0.547   , 0.547   ],
         ...,
         [0.4138  , 0.4138  , 0.4138  ],
         [0.3975  , 0.3975  , 0.3975  ],
         [0.3496  , 0.3496  , 0.3496  ]]],


       [[[0.01581 , 0.01581 , 0.01581 ],
         [0.0835  , 0.0835  , 0.0835  ],
         [0.1042  , 0.1042  , 0.1042  ],
         ...,
         [0.1624  , 0.1709  , 0.1592  ],
         [0.08594 , 0.0938  , 0.0899  ],
         [0.00784 , 0.011765, 0.011765]],

        [[0.07623 , 0.07623 , 0.07623 ],
         [0.442   , 0.442   , 0.442   ],
         [0.3748  , 0.3748  , 0.3748  ],
         ...,
         [0.2646  , 0.2747  , 0.261   ],
         [0.1082  , 0.116   , 0.11017 ],
         [0.00784 , 0.011765, 0.011765]],

        [[0.0646  , 0.0646  , 0.0646  ],
         [0.3538  , 0.3538  , 0.3538  ],
         [0.3918  , 0.3918  , 0.3918  ],
         ...,
         [0.1755  , 0.1792  , 0.1674  ],
         [0.1013  , 0.1054  , 0.10144 ],
         [0.00772 , 0.01164 , 0.01152 ]],

        ...,

        [[0.08234 , 0.0784  , 0.0844  ],
         [0.512   , 0.512   , 0.516   ],
         [0.563   , 0.563   , 0.557   ],
         ...,
         [0.9844  , 0.9844  , 0.9844  ],
         [0.9883  , 0.988   , 0.9883  ],
         [0.9883  , 0.988   , 0.9883  ]],

        [[0.0843  , 0.08264 , 0.0843  ],
         [0.506   , 0.506   , 0.506   ],
         [0.549   , 0.549   , 0.549   ],
         ...,
         [0.972   , 0.972   , 0.972   ],
         [0.9766  , 0.9766  , 0.9766  ],
         [0.9727  , 0.9727  , 0.9727  ]],

        [[0.0843  , 0.0843  , 0.0843  ],
         [0.506   , 0.506   , 0.506   ],
         [0.547   , 0.547   , 0.547   ],
         ...,
         [0.4138  , 0.4138  , 0.4138  ],
         [0.3975  , 0.3975  , 0.3975  ],
         [0.3496  , 0.3496  , 0.3496  ]]]], dtype=float16)
```

### Target : label_training_ar

- type : numpy array
- shape : (2697, 30, 2)
- example : label_training_ar[10]

```
array([[0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.]])
```

## 3. VGG19 + LSTM Model

### 3-1. Code

```
base_model=keras.applications.VGG19(include_top=False, input_shape=(160, 160, 3), weights='imagenet')

image_model=keras.models.Sequential()
image_model.add(base_model)
image_model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
image_model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc1'))
image_model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc2'))
image_model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation='softmax', name='predictions'))

chunk_size=4096
n_chunks=30
rnn_size=512

model=keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(image_model, input_shape=(30, 160, 160, 3)))

model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(rnn_size, input_shape=(n_chunks, chunk_size))) # (30, 4096)
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1024))
model.add(keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(256))
model.add(keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2))
model.add(keras.layers.Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

### 3-2. Plot image

[image]

## 4. Model Fitting (Model Training)

```
epoch=100
batchS=30
history=model.fit(x=data_training_ar[0:2000], y=label_training_ar[0:2000], epochs=epoch,
                  validation_data=(data_training_ar[2000:], label_training_ar[2000:]),
                  callbacks=[checkpoint_cb], #keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('210429_vc_13-02_checkpoint.h5', save_best_only=True)
                  batch_size=batchS, verbose=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Spyder or just notepad and run your script directly on the command line. This is to ensure your problem is not related to some timeout with the web server running Jupyter. It will also allow you to see a complete stack trace.

Comment: I failed in Google Colab, too... Is this problem related to .ipynb type file? Is my dataset too big to fit model? Many programmers have trained their model to video classification with big datasets... I really want to know how they did.

Comment: Well, to troubleshoot, figure out if you can run it directly from the command line and maybe identify the cause. Once it works on the command line, try in Jupyter

Answer (score 1):

If possible, try using PyCharm and see whether error persists or not? Also check whether it is same error or not.

I ran VGG series models in Google Colab. Its quite faster.

Comment: I failed in Google Colab, too.The session was downed, and kernal was restarted.